# eclipse galileo not responding ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, 64-bit, galileo, eclipse-3.5

I'm having a problem with eclipse galileo on ubuntu 64-bit system. when ever i open it the splash scree turns gray but keeps loading and then when eclipse opens it shows the secure storage password request and hangs. I dont know what could be wrong, it used to work fine before, if you have or had the same problem please tell me what to do

Comment: What did you change since it doesn't work anymore? Do you have the original Sun JDK installed?

Comment: yesterday i only installed the latest updates for ubuntu from the update manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try clean $HOME$/.eclipse directory.

Its better to just rename at first.

See what happens

Answer (score 9):

I have had this happen on Galileo (3.5) and Helios (3.6).

If you delete .eclipse you will lose all software installed through the Help | Install New Software menu option.

It is enough to delete the file ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security/secure_storage

Comment: This did the trick for me and was the quickest fix.  I had already done the above relating to the java-alternatives and I still got this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me whenever I shutdown eclipse with the history tab open.

While not the best solution, to solve it I start eclipse with sudo. I let it finish loading, then select a different tab than history. I Shutdown eclipse, then I recursively change the owner of the files in .metadata back to my main user.

In case you need the command: (in my case I run this from /home/wally/workspace)

```
 sudo chown -R wally:wally .metadata
```

As far as I can tell, there's some race condition going on.

(also, it's likely that you won't use exactly "wally:wally" but "your username:your group)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true
```

then run eclipse from command line from the same terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing openjdk from synaptic and install sun java. Once you do that , use "sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-6-sun" to use sun-java as the default JRE.

Eclipse used to work really slow for me, and this method worked. Maybe it helps you too.